# Ux for checkout with less clicks

Tags: checkout, printing, share

UX suggestions for making the checkout process more easy with less number of clicks. In the current Scenario - The user will add tickets to cart and navigates to the checkout screen where the user will add the visitor details and the payment details. And need to confirm the checkout process and allow the user to share and the print tickets with the same CTA button reducing the number of clicks.  Is there any other alternate way to do the checkout and print/share action together? Or any improvements need to be done in the flow?  [image]

Comment: Can we please stop saying "less clicks is better." The better way of approaching this is doing what's best **for your users.** Right here I'm seeing way too many options for no reason. What if the user doesn't want to share OR print? What if they just want to use their phone to show the ticket? Also what happens when they click +new order? Does that not allow them to confirm?

Comment: Unrelated, but "Or quickly start creating new order" sounds really weird to me. I'd just have a button that says "Create New Order"... But in a comment below you state that confirmation is a required step. Do you really just mean "Keep Shopping"?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

I see two choices here represented by two buttons. However, in both options confirm appears, so confirm is not really an option as it appears in both. Therefore, it should be part of the **compulsory flow** not the **optional flow**. What is optional is either to **print** or to **email** the tickets , (I understand).

Frankly, since the cost of sending an email is 0, get rid of this screen.

1. show ONE confirm button (if it is really needed). This button action will send the email.
2. in the email embed the option of do you want to print this ticket from your browser.

Comment: Print or share are compulsory in order to get tickets. Print or share only will confirm the order as well

Comment: gotcha, then I would use: "To complete choose one option.... --> top button "complete by SHARING" or (bottom) "complete by EMAIL"

Answer (score 0):

**Stop forcing unnecessary actions**

In this flow, you are forcing your users to either share or print. What happens if their printer doesn't have paper? What happens if they don't have a printer? What if they don't want to share? These things are not necessary actions to allow your users to move forward. *Drop them*.

**Be clear with what the page is about**

Why is there a "+ New Order?" I thought the user would have to confirm in order to get the tickets? This splits the *clear action of the page.* If you notice on most e-commerce checkouts, the confirm page has one action, and one action alone: to confirm the order. Anything else *is unnecessary noise.*

**Add secondary/tertiary actions after confirmation**

Once the user gets the email, make sure you attach the ticket via the confirmation email (I hope you are sending an email). THEN, from that email, you can lightly suggest for them to share, print, etc. Make sure the email's main goal is to show that they've got the tickets, the primary ticket details are highlighted well.

---

Please stop assuming "less clicks = less frustration." This is causing unnecessary actions to take place *in place of the best experience **for the user.*** Think about your users, and think about what **is best for them.**